# How to make an element stick to my background image, regardless of resizing?

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, sticky

So fast question I have an background-image in my header. That's 700px height. Now I want to add for example a colored square to the right bottom of this image (or another image/div etc.).

But i also want to make this square to "stick" to the background-image, also stay always on the right bottom of this image. Regardless if u make the screen narrower, or u scroll down. It just stays on the right bottom of the background-image in my header.

so my header looks something like this

```
header{
height:700px;
width:100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:top;
background-size:cover;
background-image:url....
```

}

then my text with background color that i want to have always on the bottom right:

```
.greybox{

display:inline;
width:26%;
background-color:white;
border-right:1px solid;
border-color:...;
font-weight:normal;
color:....;
line-height:20px;
padding:3%;
font-size:13px;
```

Now how can i achieve this? Espescially can i achieve it without flexbox? Coz i started doing it without flexbox but i can rewrite the code if something like this need flexbox.

Thanks for listening!

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Please include relevant code. In particular I can't see how what you have described is currently responsive. Are you using background-size: cover or similar? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: sorry, just added code.

Comment: Make the parent `position: relative;` and the child you want to stick to its bottom corner `position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0;` voila.

Comment: Doesnt do much, right:0 doesnt work. Forgot to mention maybe that my parent div1 container of greybox has display:flex, maybe thats why? And then this container div1 is child of header.

Comment: maybe easier way would be for me to just give fixed pixel value from the top and the right? Using background-position would be possible but i dont know why, it doesnt work for me

Comment: You are using background-size cover which means on some device/viewport aspect ratios the bottom right hand corner of the image wont be visible. What do you actually want? Sounds like you want the square to be within the header but as far right as possible consistent with being always visible. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that the greybox is always at the bottom of the header you can set `bottom: 0`

To make sure that it is always at the right of the header you can set `right: 0`

Note: it depends on how you are sizing the body element in which header resides as it is given 100% width.

This snippet sets the body to have width 100vw. However, if the body is of a different width then you may (or may not) wish to set the right style of the greybox to ensure it is always within the viewport. e.g. min(100%, 100vw).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
}

header {
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1024/1024);
  position: relative;
}

.greybox {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 26%;
  background-color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  /*border-color:...;*/
  font-weight: normal;
  /*color:....;*/
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 3%;
  font-size: 13px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="greybox">some text</div>
</header>
```